# How to implement RoundRobinPartitioner for Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple application, which uses Kafka Streams. The default partitioner will use the sticky partitioner under the hood when the key is `null`.
What I would like to do is to replace `DefaultStreamPartitioner` with `RoundRobinPartitioner`. However, I cannot implement it because the default implementation of `RoundRobinPartitioner` implements the `Partitioner` interface, which has `Cluster`, while the `DefaultStreamPartitioner` implements the `StreamPartitioner`, which does not have that `Cluster` instance.

```java
// Conventional partitioner
public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster)

// Stream partitioner
Integer partition(String topic, K key, V value, int numPartitions);
```

So the question is, how to implement the `RoundRobinPartitioner` for `StreamPartitioner`?

I looked through the implementation of `DefaultStreamPartitioner`, but somehow they assign the `Cluster` instance and I am not sure where I can get one.

```java
public class DefaultStreamPartitioner<K, V> implements StreamPartitioner<K, V> {

    private final Cluster cluster;
    private final Serializer<K> keySerializer;
    private final DefaultPartitioner defaultPartitioner;

    public DefaultStreamPartitioner(final Serializer<K> keySerializer, final Cluster cluster) {
        this.cluster = cluster;
        this.keySerializer = keySerializer;
        this.defaultPartitioner = new DefaultPartitioner();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer partition(final String topic, final K key, final V value, final int numPartitions) {
        final byte[] keyBytes = keySerializer.serialize(topic, key);
        return defaultPartitioner.partition(topic, key, keyBytes, value, null, cluster);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can inject Cluster into your RoundRobinPartitioner(Stream) like DefaultStreamPartitioner and do some test. Some framework will automatically inject constructor params. I'am not sure kafka streams will do it.

Comment: @Mathew In the project we don't have a dependency management framework so I think it is not possible. So it seems that the only option is to somehow provide the `Cluster` instance when creating the partitioner. But unfortunately, I couldn't find the piece of code where I can get the `Cluster` instance (may be in the admin client, but I could not find one)